# BabylonJS Matrix

Tags: javascript, matrix, babylonjs

I'm a new user of babylonJS and I wonder how to accede to values of my matrix.
For example how to accede to the case 0 0 of the BABYLON.Matrix.Identity() matrix.
Moreover, what does this matrix: pickedMesh.worldMatrix() represent ?

Does anyone know where can I find a good tutorial for understanding all of classes and method ? Because I think that the official documentation is not detailed enough.

Thank

Answer (score 0):

Hello the best idea is to start with the wiki on the github site: https://github.com/BabylonJS/Babylon.js/wiki

Matrices contain an array called m: matrix.m[0] for instance

Comment: Thanks, and what about world matrix ? That's my biggest interogation

Comment: World matrix is the matrix that represents the position/scaling/rotation of the object in the world